# How to extend an existing view model in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

For example, I create a master view model in global.js, which contains some functionalities that are used in all pages. Then, in pageA, I want to extend master view model. But I already called `ko.applybindings(masterViewModel)` in global.js. I can't change master view model in pageA.js then re-apply it, since it will cause error. 
What should I do; what's the proper way to extend an existing view model?

Comment: have you considered inheritance and `ko.applybindings` on the new object?

Comment: You could also try pulling on it really forcefully in opposite directions to see if it extends that way.

Comment: Sounds more like you need a SPA framework with a masterpage and pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is with inheritance. So you'll have your base (master) view model, and then create a new view model (for each page, as needed) that inherits the base view model. Here's an example of how you can do that (with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/keX2Q/2/)).

```
var baseModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.preference = ko.observable();
}

function pageAviewModel() {
    var self = this;
    // inherit from baseModel
    baseModel.call(self);

    self.setPreference = function () {
        // you can now utilize observables from your base model
        self.preference("Pizza");
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new pageAviewModel());
```